# How to integrate qt native window in eletron Project?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, qt, electron

Is it possible to integrate [Qt](http://wiki.qt.io/Language_Bindings) in [electron](https://electronjs.org/) application. Because I want to use one 3d viewer (developed in Qt/c++) in electron app. And that 3d viewer does not have support in electron/node. It has only support in Qt/c++.

Other suggestions also welcome.

Comment: Instead of the Qt 3d viewer you may want to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **no**. You cannot use C/C++ code directly in Electron.

Longer answer: **perhaps**, by compiling your Qt/C++ code to WebAssembly. But this may be overkill, depending on what you want to do in the end.

**alternative**: As @xmojmr mentioned, you could try if pure WebGL or a WebGL library serves your needs. I recommend to take a look [three.js](http://threejs.org), which is a popular choice for 3D graphics programming in JS.

relevant resources:

- https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_WebAssembly
- https://webassembly.org
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm

Answer (score 0):

One approach is via [Qt WebGL](https://www.ics.com/blog/whats-new-qt-510) platform plugin: the Qt Quick application becomes a web server, and you can view it in any web browser supporting webgl. You could probably also make any top-level widget work that way, backed by the experimental OpenGL ES backend, but it requires a bit of hacking.